# ComboBoxItem, IsEnabled, Binding to table value

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a dropdownlist control and its ItemsSource is a collection of items which of type T_LookupTable, which is a table in the db, and one of it's columns is 'isEnabled'.
How do I bind the IsEnabled property of the ComboBoxItem in the XAML to this value in the collection?
Further, I have numerous drop-downs in the application which employ this same method, so I would like to somehow make this a global feature if possible, through a static resource, is something like that possible?  I found this piece of XAML, which will work, but I want the items to be greyed out in the drop-down, and this method only disables them where you can't click them, but there is no visual indicator which says the item is disabled:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem"> 
        <Setter Property="Template"> 
            <Setter.Value> 
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem"> 
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=isEnabled}" /> 
                </ControlTemplate> 
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter> 
    </Style> 
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with TreeViewItems...

Basically, you have to inherit ComboBox class, override GetContainerForItemOverride method like this:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
  var result = new ComboBoxItem();
  result.SetBinding(Control.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("IsEnabled"));
  return result;
}
```

It hard codes data binding to IsEnabled property of your data object.